# Oracle report union operator

Tags: sql

How can I get the result of only First Query when the condition in the First Query satisfies in a query like Q1 Union Q2.

Comment: Why you cannot just execute Q1 alone as a new query? Or you use use INTERSECT union which returns only those rows returned by both queries. http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/sql/oracle_union_sorting.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then:

```
Q1
UNION
Q2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(Q1)
```

That is, you write Q2 so that it never returns anything if Q1 returns any rows.